# Why is strtok() not picking the '?' character from line?

Tags: c, strtok

Here below is my code in codeblocks version 13:12. It is not commented because I laid it down quick to ask here having lost my hair! My concern is that I expect my `char *` target  to be `/cat.html?name=image` but I only get `/cat.html`!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    const char *space = " ";
    const char *marker = "?";
    const char line[] = { "GET /cat.html?name=image HTTP/1.1" };
    int n = strlen(line), i, j, k, a;
    char string[n + 1];

    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        string[i] = line[i];
        string[n] = '\0';
    }
    printf(" line has %i characters \n\n", n);
    char *method = strtok(string, space);
    char *target = strtok(NULL, space);
    char *version = strtok(NULL, space);

    char *abs_path = strtok(target, marker);
    char *query = strtok(NULL, marker);

    printf("\n line is:%s \n"
           "\n method is:%s \n"
           "\n target is:%s \n"
           "\n version     is:%s \n"
           "\n abs_path is:%s \n"
           "\n query is:%s \n\n\n",
           line, method, target, version, abs_path, query);

    int l = strlen(target);
    if (strcmp(method, "GET") != 0) {
        printf("wrong method error 405 \n\n");
    }

    printf(" target contains %i characters \n\n", l);
    for (j = 0; j <= l; j++) {
        if (target[0] != '/') {
            printf("wrong target does not start with \\/error 501\n\n");
        }
        if (target[j] == '"') {
            printf("wrong target error 400 has a \" \n\n");
        }
    }
    if (strchr(abs_path, '.') == NULL) {
        printf("wrong absolute path has no \. \n\n");
    }
    if (strncmp(version, "HTTP/1.1", 8) != 0) {
        printf("wrong version not HTTP/1.1 error 505 \n\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is playing with fire given `const char line[] = "…";`.  If you wrote `line[4] = line[4];`, the compiler would prevent you because you can't modify a constant array.  However, you pass that array to `strtok()` which tramples over the array, writing nulls at various points in the array.  That isn't guaranteed to work.  Remove the `const` from the definition of `line`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtok()` modifies the buffer passed aa the first argument. After the first 3 calls, `method`, `target` and `version` are either `NULL` or point so the `string` array to fragments corresponding to the first, second and third space delimited parts.

```
char *method = strtok(string, space);
char *target = strtok(NULL, space);
char *version = strtok(NULL, space);
```

`method` points to `"GET"` at `string+0`, `string[3]` has been set to `'\0'`
`target` points to `"/cat.html?name=image"` at `string+4`, `string[24]` is set to `'\0'`.
`version` points to `"HTTP/1.1"` at `string+25`.

When you issue further calls to `strtok` on `target`, the `string` array will be modified and the `?` will be overwritten with a `'\0'`.

```
char *abs_path = strtok(target, marker);
char *query = strtok(NULL, marker);
```

`abs_path` points to `"/cat.html"` at `string+4`, `string[13]` is set to `'\0'`.
`query` points to `"name=image"` at `string+14`.

If you want to preserve the string pointed to by `target`, you must make a copy before the second set of calls to `strtok():

```
char *saved_target = strdup(target);
char *abs_path = strtok(target, marker);
char *query = strtok(NULL, marker);
```

And use it in the `printf`:

```
    printf("\n line is:%s \n"
           "\n method is:%s \n"
           "\n target is:%s \n"
           "\n version     is:%s \n"
           "\n abs_path is:%s \n"
           "\n query is:%s \n\n\n",
           line, method, saved_target, version, abs_path, query);
```

Comment: thanks a lot @chqrlie. You made it even clearer. I will try to make a copy manually even without using strdup() seeing as I am learning C [want to get it from first principles]. Thanks again, it worked well.

Answer (score 3):

```
char * method = strtok(string, space);
char * target = strtok(NULL, space);
char * version = strtok(NULL, space);
```

After those lines, `target` *does* indeed have the value `"/cat.html?name=image"`. The problem is that you then call strtok again on `target` which will modify the string:

```
abs_path = strtok(target, marker);
```

After that line, `target` will then have the value `"/cat.html"`

If you want to preserve the original value of `target` you need to make a copy of it before the second `strtok`. on `target`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @kaylum, that made a lot of sense and help to me. I see I must have interrupted strtok() while invoking it for abs_path.